# How to read a file via ASP.Net Web API to S3 via Memory Stream

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api2

I want to read file as memory stream and send it to s3 bucket. Below is a working snippet which has two part.

Part 1: Takes a file and upload it to a local directory

Part 2: Takes a text and upload it to s3 bucket.

But *I want to upload the file to s3 bucket rather than the text*.

Below is the code snippet:

```
[httppost]    
public async void Upload()
{
        // Part 1:

        // LOGIC TO UPLOAD FILE TO A LOCAL LOCATION 
        var fileuploadPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadLocation"];  // some local path
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileuploadPath);
        var content = new StreamContent(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true));
        foreach (var header in Request.Content.Headers)
        {
            content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
        await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        // Part 2:

        // LOGIC TO WRITE DATA TO s3 Bucket via Amazon Kinesis
        byte[] dataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My Test Data for s3 bucket");
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(dataAsBytes))
        {
                Amazon.KinesisFirehose.Model.PutRecordRequest putRecord = new Amazon.KinesisFirehose.Model.PutRecordRequest();
                putRecord.DeliveryStreamName = myStreamName;
                Record record = new Record();
                record.Data = memoryStream; // I WANT TO PUT FILE CONTENT HERE
                putRecord.Record = record;
                await kinesisClient.PutRecordAsync(putRecord);
        }
}
```

In above code snippet, I want to send the file that is getting uploaded to s3 bucket.

**Psuedo Code:**

```
Current Code
byte[] dataAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My Test Data for s3 bucket");
What I want
byte[] dataAsByte = Data should be read from the file
```

Comment: @John: Can you kindly guide me a little please.

Comment: This is what I want, but I am not sure how to plug your code. File.OpenRead returns `filestream`, how to put it in memory stream. Also, how to get the `filename`. I am a beginner so please bear with me.

Comment: Sorry to say but I guess you would have to post an answer for me. I am not able to use Stream because `record.Data` explicitly expects `Memory Stream`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188259/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-john).

Answer (score 2):

You could read all bytes and construct a memory stream:

```
string fileName = provider.FileData.First().LocalFileName; // assuming you have one file
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileData))
{
```

Note that the maximum size allowed in that field is [50kb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_Kinesis_Model_PutRecordRequest_Data.htm) so you might want to add validation for this.

Comment: could not find method `BodyPartFileNames`.

Comment: @Unbreakable Sorry, check now.